# Rails RSpec script fails to identify elements (update: because they are in iframe)

Tags: iframe, selenium-webdriver, rspec-rails, automated-tests

I am new to `Rails` and `Selenium` but have used other automated testing tools.

I exported a script from the Selenium 2 IDE to Rails/RSpec and am altering the code to get it to run. The script fails to find a specific link.

The original Ruby code as exported from the working IDE script was:

```
@driver.find_element(:link, "skip").click
```

This failed, so I attempted to identify the element with an XPath statement. (There were other elements that failed in the originally exported code that I **fixed** by using XPath, so that’s why I am using this strategy.)

I tried different alternatives to identify the link in the Ruby code, such as:

Attempt #1:`@driver.find_element(:XPath, "//*[@class='skip-link']").click`

Attempt #2:`@driver.find_element(:XPath, "//*[@value='skip']").click`

Result in all cases: `Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"skip"}`

HTML reported per Firebug:

```
<a style="float: right; margin-right: 10px; text-decoration: none;" href="/yourfuture" class="skip-link"> skip </a>
```

XPath reported per Firebug:

```
/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div[4]/a
```

I have timeout set to 60 seconds and see the link **skip** displayed for several seconds before the script fails, so I don’t this is an issue.

One possibly relevant fact: when the app presents the window with all the controls, the **skip** does not appear initially. By program design, the app waits about 5 seconds before.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the link that was not seen was in an iFrame. The attributes of the iframe changed so it was difficult to identify it with a static property, so I just inserted the following line of code just before the line that Webdriver could not "see":

```
@driver.switch_to.frame(0)
```

I could have also used `@driver.switch_to.frame("iframe-identifier-per-swtich")` if there was a reliable way of identifying the iframe.

Yeah, you probably knew that but maybe this will help another newbie avoid the same problem.